# Grails app runs locally but won't run within Docker container

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, grails, dockerfile

I've got an app built in Grails 3.3 that I'm trying to get running within a Docker container. I'm building the app with a simple `grails package` command which creates a WAR file in the build/libs directory of the project. I am not using any of the options to build a self-contained, executable JAR file. However, I found that I can still launch the app directly by using this command:

```
java -jar -Dgrails.env=prod -Dserver.port=9000 build/libs/myapp-0.1.war
```

When run directly from my local machine (terminal), this actually works fine. The application takes about a minute to start up, but eventually does and I see this message in the terminal:

> Grails application running at http://localhost:9000 in environment: production

However, I am trying to replicate this same setup within a Docker container, and there it fails. Here's the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM java:8
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY ./build/libs/myapp-0.1.war /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "-Dgrails.env=prod", "-Dserver.port=80", "myapp-0.1.war"]
```

I build that Docker image using `docker build -t myapp:latest .` and then try to run it using `docker run -p 9000:80 -it myapp:latest`. And it appears to start up, just as it does when running things locally. However, it inevitably spits out an error message similar to this one:

```
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.
Message: Error creating bean with name 'logoutFilterDeregistrationBean':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logoutFilter' while setting bean property 'filter';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'logoutSuccessHandler':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redirectStrategy' while setting bean property 'redirectStrategy';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'redirectStrategy':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myCustomService' while setting bean property 'myCustomService';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'myCustomService': Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'myCustomService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'com.mydomain.custom.MyCustomDao' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field dao in com.mydomain.custom.MyCustomService required a bean of type 'com.mydomain.custom.MyCustomDao' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mydomain.custom.MyCustomDao' in your configuration.
```

It doesn't make sense to me that this same command (`java -jar`) which I use to launch the WAR file *would* work on my local machine but *would not* work within a Docker container. This to me, would imply that the `java:8` base image is missing something that my local system has which is needed to run this WAR file. The error about not auto-wiring the bean seems to me a bit of a red herring, and irrelevant to whatever real problem is going on (because that autowire problem doesn't happen when I run locally). Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, it makes no sense!

Comment: Do you have any other files in `/build/libs`? Maybe your `WAR` file does not contain bean definition `MyCustomDao`.

Comment: Without access to the project, I can't tell from your description what is wrong but maybe you will find the sample at https://github.com/grails-samples/music helpful. The `README.md` there describes how to launch the docker container and you can see in `build.gradle` how I am describing the image.  One difference is I am using `williamyeh/java8`.  Not sure if that will be relevant, but maybe something to try.  Also, there is probably no good reason for you to use a `.war`. If you remove the `war` plugin from your build `./gradlew assemble` will build an executable `.jar`.  Good luck!

Comment: Don't use https://hub.docker.com/_/java/ - it's deprecated for 1.5 years now.  Use https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/ instead.

Comment: @BukharovSergey nothing else in `build/libs/` (besides a myapp-0.1.war.original file, which is the exact same file size as the war file). There is plenty in `build/` however. I am not sure but I've now discovered that if I copy the war file to some other directory and try to run it locally from there it also fails to run, for the same reason that the Dockerized version failed to run. So perhaps the WAR file is expecting to find files in the build folder one level up? That seems like errant behavior to me.

Comment: "That seems like errant behavior to me." - Agreed, but there isn't enough info here to know if the problem is in your app or in the framework.  Do you have anything that is hardcoded to look at a relative path?

Comment: Obviously apps are deployed all of the time as a `.war` or a `.jar` so there isn't anything fundamental in the framework that prevents that.  I suspect something in the app, but it is hard to say without seeing an example.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I would love to have you dive in and pinpoint the issue; unfortunately as this is a work project I have to be intentionally cryptic as I'm not allowed to disclose the code. I'll keep at it and update this whenever I find the root cause.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown just an update, again very odd behavior. If I create an empty directory called `grails-app` in the directory that I launch things from, then it *does* work. But if I delete that (empty) directory then it fails to launch.